# Where is the sampling menu in Blender version 2.77?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

Where is the *Properties panel > Sampling menu* in Blender version 2.77? I want to reduce the noise in an object.

Answer (score 3):

You are currently in Blender Render. Change to Cycles at the top of the screen.

[image]

to

[image]

Alternately, if you want to reduce noise in a Blender Internal render, select the light, go to the *Properties panel > Object Data tab > Shadow dropdown* and increase the light's samples.

[image]

Comment: Great answer! Giving options and for both engines. Great!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's for cycles only, I find that the final render is always grainy when I add lights or glossy materials, If you get fire flies on your final render try adjusting the clamp settings to whatever suits your scene, Hope this helps you :)